# Journey logic check

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have a subscription program and I've created a campaign in two stages, 2 weeks prior to expiry, and 1 day after expiry of the subscription.

I have an automation that pulls the customers every day that have the expiry day 2 weeks before current date. This is the entry source of my journey.

I'm also doing an A/B test to check if the customers who are receiving an email are more likely to resubscribe or not so I have created two pots, pot A and Pot B and with another automation I combine them into one data extension.

In the journey I have the property filter SubscriptionEndDate is after Today.

The problem is that nobody got the stage 2 of the email and I don't understand why?

Can you see anything wrong with the data or setting up the journey? Thanks!

This is the journey
[image: This is the Journey]

All the pots
[image]

Pot A and B
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely, that you are using Journey Data rather than Contact Data in the decision split. In that case journey builder always checks against the data that was present in the data extension at the time your contact entered the journey, hence the old date.

**Further information:**

- [Journey and Contact Data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data.htm&type=5)
- [Journey and Contact Data in Decision Splits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_jb_journey_contact_data_decision_splits.htm&type=5)